# What should be the path for file upload in Parellel Plex Hosting Java application.

Tags: java, exception, servlets, plesk

I am having a web application deployed on the remote host as the war file. Currently i am uploading images directly into the Blob field of the database. I want to store them outside the database now because of the database space issue. I have given the path of **httpdocs** folder provided by default. But i am getting the path not found exception.

```
 <context-param>
 <description>Location to store uploaded file</description>
 <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
 <param-value>httpdocs/img/
 </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

But i am getting a path not found exception.

So what path should i provide to upload the files.

I am having this folder structure on my plesk panel

```
Root directory
.plesk
cgi-bin
error_docs
httpdocs
logs
```

Comment: have you tried this path `/httpdocs/img/` ?

Comment: no i haven't tried it yet, should i try?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara I have tried it and getting this exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: \httpdocs\img\ankit.jpg (The system cannot find the path specified) at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method) at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at java.io.FileOutputStream.(Unknown Source) at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.`

Comment: are not appending you context before the start of the file path? Try that.

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara didn't get you clearly ,the code i have used is `if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 )
            {
             file = new File( filePath + 
               fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
            }` where should i change

Comment: I mean have you tried adding your context path like "http://your_webapp/img/"?

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara    Actually I have deployed the war file through the Parallels Plesk, and httpdocs is the root directory.